# What is the core reason for "Signature verification failed" error?

Tags: anchor, solana-program

I am getting "Signature verification failed" error for my program even if there are no constraints for signers in the program (permissionless).

Also checked that the signer is properly defined before sending transaction. This error occurs only sometimes, where most times it succeeds.

What are the core reasons for this error when submitting tx via anchor on ts?

Comment: can you give more reference about error
and also code for this

Answer (score 0):

```
it("An account is initialized", async function() {
    const baseAccount  = Keypair.generate();
    const initializeTx = await program.methods.initialize("My first message").accounts({
      baseAccount: baseAccount.publicKey,
        user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
        systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
//    }).signers([baseAccount]).rpc()
```

This is a common issue raised when we don't provide a signer
for an instruction like in this commented line we need a signer for this account
named baseAccount

you need to provide a signer

Comment: I am setting the AnchorProvider with the signer, which means this is not required? Even though I set .signers, it happens only in certain occasions, like 1 out of 50 txs.

Comment: can you provide a reference code

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to initialize a new data account on the program, the wallet occasionally wants the account to be a signer.
You can easily fix it to change the ABI of the program.
You can change the account isSigner as true.